# Entity Framework: Connect to an external database

Tags: entity-framework, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4, database-connection

I have created application under MS VS 2012 express. I am using Entity Framework to access local database SQL Server Compact 4.0. Everything works just fine:

Web.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
   <add name="KMDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\kmdbs.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

LessonsL.cs

```
public class KMDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<LessonsL> LessonsLs { get; set; }
}
```

LessonsLController.cs

```
private KMDBContext db = new KMDBContext();
```

But I am not able to connect to external SQL Server database. Test Connection returns positive results. I can work with the external database using MS Server Management Studio. But can not retrieve or store data. I can see the external database in Database Explorer but MS VS 2012 still connects to some local file (pdb or something).

Web.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LessonLs" connectionString="server=ustsql;database=LessonLs;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

kmd.cs

```
public class KMDContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<kmd> LessonsLs { get; set; }
}
```

KMDController.cs

```
private KMDContext db = new KMDContext();
```

Could anyone say what I am missing? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of your connection string still needs to be "KMDContext", since that is the name of your DbContext.

Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="KMDContext" connectionString="server=ustsql;database=LessonLs;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: This just rename Data Conections in Database Explorer, but still app is connectiong to local file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem was in connecting to the existing table on SQL Server. I created the table first, then was trying to connect to it.

Once I deleted all, application on my local PC and table on SQL Server, and created app again from scratch I was able to work with the external SQL database.
Table in external SQL database was then automatically created by app from local PC.

Anyway, **thanks ckal**, the whole problem seems to be in the naming conventions. From beginning I wasn't working with the correct names.

The actual working code:

**Web.config**

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="KMD1DBContext" connectionString="server=ustsql;database=LessonLs;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**KMD1.cs**

```
public class KMD1
{
    ...
}

public class KMD1DBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<KMD1> kmds { get; set; }
}
```

**KMD1Controller.cs**

```
private KMD1DBContext db = new KMD1DBContext();
```

**Name of the table in external SQL database**

```
KMD1
```